# What security issues could my system be exposed to via an unsecure memory card?

Tags: exploit, attacks, flash-memory

I'm working on an article that involves flash memory cards being put into machines that process and track sensitive information. The machines scan data from forms, then input the data into a database.

Supposing memory cards went unchecked and were put into these machines, what sorts of vulnerabilities might this system be exposed to?

Comment: From firmware to software. All code that handles the device and data processing could potentially contain vulnerabilities and could lead to system compromise, data exfiltration etc.